# How to set form type as 'hierarchical_select' programatically?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I am using the following code to create a form in Drupal 6. This code displays a drop down filter with which I can select the terms, and apply the filters using the GET method.

```
function sample_create_form () {
  $vid=2;
  $options = taxonomy_form($vid, $value = 0, $help = NULL, $name = 'sample');
  $form['#method'] = 'get';

  $form['option'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Terms for the Website'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#description' => t('Website category'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'submit', 
   '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form; 
}
```

I want to display the form as a Hierarchical Select type. I tried to use 'hierarchical_select' instead of 'select' in the above code but it didn't work.

Is there a way by which we can get the hierarchical select form?

I am using Drupal 6 and I have hierarchical select module enabled.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its better to use hierarchical_select for element as it gives a FORM API that is really easy to use. Check the following snippet as reference

```
$form['hierarchical_select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="hierarchical_select" class="hierarchical_select_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('hierarchical-select'),
    ),
);
$form['hierarchical_select']['select_subject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hierarchical_select',
    '#title' => t('Select the tag you wish to use.'),
    '#size' => 1,
    '#config' => array(
        'module' => 'hs_taxonomy',
        'params' => array(
            'vid' => 13 //The vocab id
        ),
        'save_lineage' => 1,
        'enforce_deepest' => 0,
        'entity_count' => 0,
        'require_entity' => 0,
        'resizable' => 1,
        'level_labels' => array(
            'status' => 1,
            'labels' => array(
                0 => t('Grade'),
                1 => t('Subject'),
                2 => t('Main Topic'),
                3 => t('Sub Topic'),
                4 => t('Standard'),
                5 => t('Sub-Standard'),
            ),
        ),
        'dropbox' => array(
            'status' => 0,
            'title' => t('All selections'),
            'limit' => 0,
            'reset_hs' => 1,
        ),
        'editability' => array(
            'status' => 0,
            'item_types' => array(),
        ),
        'animation_delay' => 400,
        'special_items' => array(),
       'render_flat_select' => 0,
       'path' => 'hierarchical_select_json',
    ),
    '#default_value' => 0,
);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I was looking for:) Thanks a lot aneek :)

Comment: I've tried to use this code in hierarchical_select-7.x-3.x but is doesnt quite work. There are several deprecated function from hs 2.x to 3.x. is there an updated example of this code available?

Comment: @JohnR this might happen. This was with a old module. The module itself has an api.php and readme. Have you had a look at those?

Comment: Yes, I've been fumbling through it for a few days now... I was using the readme, this post, [Wim Leer's HS repo](https://github.com/wimleers/wimleers.com-modules/tree/master/hsdemo) and this [link](http://thedotwriter.com/how-to-use-hierarchical-select-hooks-in-drupal-7/) to try and update. I'm making progress very slowly... but i could certainly use some pointers.