# how to add existing taxonomy in custom form

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a dependent drop down created using taxonomy and hierarchical select in Drupal 6. I want to add this in a custom form. Is this possible?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "add it" - do you want a dropdown with all terms? And please paste relevant part of your form, the one where you have a problem.

Comment: Please check this.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54812/how-to-set-form-type-as-hierarchical-select-programatically